# How do I grep output of logs with dynamic columns

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

Log file:

```
2015-11-29 02:24:14,053 DEBUG ExcludePostalCodesServiceImpl [messageListenerContainer-38] :88 - Postal Code : 5118 is Excluded for country : AU
2015-11-29 02:24:14,077  INFO BatchExecutionListener [messageListenerContainer-35] :29 - ----------FINISH JOB: shipmentJob, JOB_INSTANCE_ID: 121453924, EXIT_CODE: COMPLETED----------
2015-11-29 02:24:14,054  INFO ShipmentRuleRunnerImpl [messageListenerContainer-38] :83 - Shipment is not selected due to exclusion postal code: [awb=40738xxxxx, shp_acct_no=7612xxxxx, rcvr_name=xxxxx, rcvr_org=CAROLxxx, org_ctry=US, dest_ctry=AU, dest_addr=xxxxxxxx,
```

Say the above file is a huge one. I would like to :

1) grep -B 3 "Shipment is not selected due to exclusion postal code" xxxx.log
 - This is to grep the keyword that I require, and return 3 lines before

2) I would like to then, filter out lines containing [messageListenerContainer-38] , in this example so that output would be as below. Note that the [messageListenerContainer-35] is missing as I only want the the one that is associated with the first keyword grep.

```
2015-11-29 02:24:14,053 DEBUG ExcludePostalCodesServiceImpl [messageListenerContainer-38] :88 - Postal Code : 5118 is Excluded for country : AU
2015-11-29 02:24:14,054  INFO ShipmentRuleRunnerImpl [messageListenerContainer-38] :83 - Shipment is not selected due to exclusion postal code: [awb=40738xxxxx, shp_acct_no=7612xxxxx, rcvr_name=xxxxx, rcvr_org=CAROLxxx, org_ctry=US, dest_ctry=AU, dest_addr=xxxxxxxx,
```

`grep -B 3 "Shipment is not selected due to exclusion postal code" xxx.log | grep [messageListenerContainer-38]`

works if the tag is unique all the time, but if I were to grep from a huge list of logs (returning multiple results), the number in xx [messageListenerContainer-xx] is dynamic.

It will also be reused after some time, hence I would have to restrict the grep -B to 5 to only grep a certain amount of lines before that is relevant. (nature of logs)

Hence, is it possible to grep a few lines before a certain keyword AND then do a further filter to only take ones with the [messageListenerContainer-xx] associated with the first grep?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamic"? What "threads" are you talking about? I'm having trouble guessing what the output should look like based on your description.  Could you include a couple of samples of differing input, with the appropriate output for each input sample? Also, is your preferred solution Linux-specific? (Wondering about the tag.)

Comment: Hi ghoti, 

This will be dynamic (the numbers behind): messageListenerContainer-38

The number 35 indicates the thread. It will be reused over and over again, hence it is not unique.

As such, I need to first grep out a pattern. As there are information required on lines ABOVE the patten that i want to grep, I need to include several lines before. However, several lines before will also ahve messages frmo other threads (eg messageListenerContainer-42). 

How can I filter my output to only be the one that I want? (based on pattern above on first grep)

Comment: What is your output supposed to look like? How many is "several"? Is the line you need to keep always that thread's message immediately before your search string? Is there a log line that indicates the start of activity on a thread? What about a line that indicates the end of activity on a thread? Please edit your question with clarification. Comments should be for comments, not for critical information that clarifies your requirements. Oh, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: H ghoti, I'm sorry for the confusion. I have edited the post, and hopefully you get what I'm trying to say. Basically, I would like to grep 5 lines before my keyword (which returns MULTIPLE results)  and then grep ONLY the ones with the same XX as in [messageListenerContainer-XX], within those 5 lines.

Comment: You're talking about wanting do something 5 lines before a keyword but you only show 3 lines of sample input. If you expect us to make up our own sample input and output files so we can start to help you you may be surprised...

Comment: Hi Ed, let's say the lines do not matter. (let's put it as 3 before)

Is it possible to sort of keep the [messageListenerContainer-XX] in a variable, and then use it to grep from the FIRST grep output?

Comment: I REALLY wish you weren't being so frugal with your sample input/output. You're talking about FIRST grep output but your input only contains one line that matches your grep regexp so idk if you're talking about ignoring later lines matching that regexp or selecting some id XX from the first grep and using it to select lines from later in the file or something else. Your problem will be absolutely trivial to solve in awk once you can clean up and enhance your question to clearly tell/show us what the problem is.

Comment: @JCDrew90 - you are likely to get a very good answer if you merely go through the requests for clarification in these comments and update your question to include everything they mention. Up to you, I won't spend further time on this without more input. I will, however, point you to [something loosely related](https://github.com/chvostek/shelltools/blob/master/mailqgrep) I wrote a while ago. It's not as elegant solution as something purpose-built for your data, but it might provide an example of how you can proceed yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/[^\n]+/&/3;$!Ta;/\n[^\n]*Shipment bla bla [^\n]*$/!D;:b;/^[^\n]*(messageListenerContainer -[0-9]+ ).*\n[^\n]*\1[^\n]*$/P;s/^[^\n]*\n//;tb' file
```

The solution is in two parts. First a rolling window of n lines (in this case 3) is selected and the last (or first depending on your view) line of window is matched with the required string (in this case `Shipment bla bla`). Having established that the lines in the pattern space meet the required criteria, using pattern matching the first and last lines are compared to see if they meet the second criteria i.e. `messageListenerContainer - ...`. If so the first line is printed and reguardless then deleted. This is repeated until all lines are processed and then the last line is printed.

Comment: Nice. And not arcane at all. I don't know what people are talking about, sed is beautiful. :-P

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
$ awk -v n=4      '{p=p%n;a[p++]=$0} 
   /search_pattern/{key=$5; 
                    for(i=p;i<p+n;i++) 
                      {line=a[i%n]; 
                       if(line ~ key) print line}}' log    

X X X X X-38 XXXX
X X X X X-38 XXXX
X X X X X-38 search_pattern
```

where

```
$ cat log
X X X X X-35 XXXX
X X X X X-35 XXXX
X X X X X-35 XXXX
X X X X X-38 XXXX
X X X X X-35 XXXX
X X X X X-38 XXXX
X X X X X-38 search_pattern
X X X X XXXX XXX
```

for the searched pattern look back for `n` lines and print the lines that are correlated with the key ($5) field.  For exact match you can change regex match `~` with equality `==`.